# Update MySQL with SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

Is it possible for me to have a MySQL database (on a server) that is updated from an 'offline' SQLite database, somehow?

Like if I submit form to SQLite and have the MySQL refresh to reflect the latest changes (deriving those changes from the SQLite)?

Comment: you want both databases to take same chages

Comment: I would like it so that when I insert into the SQLite offline, I can somehow update MySQL when I get back online (having an internet connection).

So I guess that's a yes, partially.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an abstraction layer, select all the records from SQLite, then insert the ones that don't exist into the MySQL database, or you could just add the record into the MySQL DB at the same time as adding the record into the SQLite DB.